# safe and performing way to save site wide variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, global

I am building a rails app, have a site wide counter variable (counter) that is used (read and write) by different pages, basically many pages can cause the counter increment, what is a multi-thread-safe way to store this variable so that 
1) it is thread-safe, I may have many concurrent user access might read and write this variable 
2) high performing, I originally thought about persist this variable in DB, but wondering is there a better way given there can be high volume of request and I don't want to make this DB query the bottleneck of my app...

suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether it has to be perfectly accurate.  Assuming not, you can store it in [memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) and sync to the database occasionally.  If memcached crashes, it expires (shouldn't happen if configured properly), you have to shutdown, etc., reload it from the database on startup.

You could also look at [membase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membase).  I haven't tried it, but to simplify, it's a distributed memcached server that automatically persists to disk.

For better performance and accuracy, you could look at a sharded approach.

Comment: this variable is "mission critical" and must be 100% accurate, because I use it as a key to store/retrieve other user data. with that, I guess the only option is to persist to DB - If I have to do this, is there a best practice to build a MySql query that is high performing, I estimate the read and write ratio is about 10:1...

Comment: @Twinkiestar, it sounds like you may want to use a traditional relational database with foreign keys to your user table.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need persistence, so you have to store it in the Database/Session/File, AFAIK.